# What would be the word to describe the following

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, vocabulary, british-english

You are working in your office. There is a candidate who is waiting outside to be interviewed.
Its been half and hour and nobody has gotten up to go and conduct the interview. 
You are feeling uneasy because you kind of feel bad because the poor candidate has been waiting for so long even though 
its not your fault. So you finally ask your colleague to go and interview the candidate. 
What would would describe what you are feeling at that moment that prompted you to ask your colleague to go and conduct the interview?

It's not guilt, its not pity.

Comment: Idiomatically, 'I feel [really] bad about/that ...' would often be used.

Comment: 'A sense of common decency'?

Comment: Who says it's not pity, please?

Uneasy; kind of bad; uncomfortable; empathy; sympathy; responsible (very clearly: you asked your colleague…); distracted; concerned; bored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean "*empathy*" or "*human solidarity*"?

Comment: I don't think 'human solidarity" would fit in a sentence here. 
I asked my friend to conduct the interview out of human solidarity? 
Empathy sounds alright i guess.+1

Comment: I think you're right: "_human solidarity_" would rather belong in a newspaper article.

Answer (score -1):

You're feeling *Indignant*

Indignant via [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/indignant)

> Adjective: feeling, characterized by, or expressing strong displeasure at something considered unjust, offensive, insulting

Another appropriate word with a lighter connotation may be *Sympathetic*

Sympathy via [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sympathy)

> The fact or power of sharing the feelings of another, especially in sorrow or trouble; fellow feeling, compassion, or commiseration.